# How to get information from objdump

Tags: assembly, binutils, objdump

I encounter a problem when reading information dumped out from an executable file in linux.
The information is as follows:

```
804a0ea:  04 08            add $0x8, %al
     ...
804a0f4:  a6               cmpsb %es:(%edi),%ds:(%esi)
```

I have two questions:

1. what does the address 804a0ea and 804a0f4 mean? the virtual address in the process's address space?
2. what does the ... mean? how can I get instruction at address 804a0f0?

Thanks in advance.

More information around this part of code:

```
Disassembly of section .got.plt:

    0804a0e8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
     804a0e8:       14 a0                   adc    $0xa0,%al
     804a0ea:       04 08                   add    $0x8,%al
            ...
     804a0f4:       a6                      cmpsb  %es:(%edi),%ds:(%esi)
     804a0f5:       87 04 08                xchg   %eax,(%eax,%ecx,1)
     804a0f8:       b6 87                   mov    $0x87,%dh
     804a0fa:       04 08                   add    $0x8,%al
     804a0fc:       c6 87 04 08 d6 87 04    movb   $0x4,-0x7829f7fc(%edi)
     804a103:       08 e6                   or     %ah,%dh
     804a105:       87 04 08                xchg   %eax,(%eax,%ecx,1)
     804a108:       f6 87 04 08 06 88 04    testb  $0x4,-0x77f9f7fc(%edi)
     804a10f:       08 16                   or     %dl,(%esi)
     804a111:       88 04 08                mov    %al,(%eax,%ecx,1)
     804a114:       26 88 04 08             mov    %al,%es:(%eax,%ecx,1)
     804a118:       36 88 04 08             mov    %al,%ss:(%eax,%ecx,1)
     804a11c:       46                      inc    %esi
```

Hope anyone can give me a hand.:-)

Comment: I think you need to add a little bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [global offset table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-74186.html#scrolltoc) is not pointing to code, it's pointing to data (hrm... offsets, actually). So trying to disassemble it will not give very meaningful code. (you can actually find which offsets by looking at the code values. 0804a014, ... 080487a6).

The ... usually mean a bunch of 0's are in the stream.

Comment: I recognized this shortly after I post this question. Since I newly come here, I don't know how to close the thread :-). Thank you all the same. By the way, does address 0x0804a014 the virtual address in the process's address space?

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy only the assembly code to the text editor
2. On the first line type main: (assembly for main())
3. And save the file as a *.s
4. Open terminal and type gcc -s  -o  to compile
   or type in terminal gdb  
   and then type layout asm and type then print